# How to send data between two phones running my app using cellular data

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, p2p

I'd like to have my app able to create P2P connections between users over both wifi and cellular (if wifi is available I'll use it but it needs to support cellular too).

I've seen many questions/answers relating to wifi but none for cellular. Is this possible?

If it is, are there any libraries/packages out there that help do it?

The solution would also need to support both iOS and Android and be cross-compatible between the two.

Comment: You need a server in the internet to provide some sort of "rendezvous". You may be able to establish a peer to peer Internet connection (some service providers will use NAT that makes this impossible) but you need to know the IP address of both parties. This is what your server can do. Each device would need to connect to your server and then the server can provide the "other" IAP address to each party

Comment: The problem is going to be how two phones in physical proximity are going to discover each other. I'm on AT&T, the person two feet away from me is on Verizon. (Even if we were on the same carrier, the same problem applies, but the different carrier scenario brings the problem into stark relief.) There's no way one is going to be able to discover the other via cellular, alone. You could have both submit location data to your web service (and it figures out geographic proximity) or rely on other local mechanisms, e.g. BLE, WiFi, ultrasound, etc.).